# Extract text between the Tags

Tags: notepad++, regex, grep

I am trying to extract Arabic text between the two tags. Here its `<Content>some text in arabic</Content>`

**Sample Text:**

```
<idPkg:Story xmlns:idPkg="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/idml/1.0/packaging" DOMVersion="19.0">
    <Story Self="uf3" AppliedTOCStyle="n" UserText="true" IsEndnoteStory="false" TrackChanges="false" StoryTitle="$ID/" AppliedNamedGrid="n">
        <StoryPreference OpticalMarginAlignment="false" OpticalMarginSize="12" FrameType="TextFrameType" StoryOrientation="Horizontal" StoryDirection="RightToLeftDirection" />
        <InCopyExportOption IncludeGraphicProxies="true" IncludeAllResources="false" />
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/heading">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>مسلمان /آنحضرت صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم</Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/description">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>ابو الخیر کا رویا میں آنحضرت صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم کو دیکھنا :</Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/body">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>لوگ سمجھ لیتے ہیں کہ ہم مومن ہیں اور مسلمان ہیں لیکن دراصل وہ نہیں ہوتےزبانی  اقرار تو ایک آسان بات ہےلیکن کر کے دکھانا اور بات ہے ۔خدا تعالیٰ فرماتا ہے کہ اَحَسِبَ النَّاسُ اَنۡ یُّتۡرَکُوۡۤا اَنۡ یَّقُوۡلُوۡۤا اٰمَنَّا وَہُمۡ لَا یُفۡتَنُوۡنَ ﴿۳﴾ (العنکبوت :3)یعنی کیا لوگ گمان کرتے ہیں کہ وہ مومن اور پکے ایماندار ہیں اور ابھی وہ آزمائے نہیں گئے۔پس جب تک آزمائش نہ ہو ایمان کوئی حقیقت نہیں رکھتا۔بہت لوگ ہیں جو آزمائش کے وقت پھسل جاتے ہیں اور تکلیف کے وقت ان کا ایمان ڈگمگا جاتا ہے۔</Content>
                <Br />
                <Content>ایک یہودی کا قصہ ہے جو کہ ایک بہت بڑا طبیب گزرا ہے اور جس کا نام ابوالخیر تھا ۔کہ ایک دفعہ وہ ایک کوچہ  میں سے گزر رہا تھا ۔جبکہ اس نے ایک شخص کو یہ پڑھتے ہوئے سُنا اَحَسِبَ النَّاسُ اگرچہ وہ یہودی تھا اُس نے آیت کو سن کر اپنے ہاتھوں سے ایک دیوار پر ٹیک لگا لی اور سر جھکا کر رونے لگا۔جب رو چکا تو اپنے گھر آیا اور جب وہ سو گیا تو اس نے دیکھا کہ آنحضرت صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم تشریف لائے اور انہوں نے فرمایا کہ اے ابوالخیر تعجب ہے کہ تیرے جیسا فضل و کمال والا انسان مسلمان نہ ہو۔صبح جب اٹھا تو اس نے تمام شہر میں اعلان کر دیا کہ میں آج سے مذہب اسلام قبول کرتا ہوں۔</Content>
                <Br />
                <Content>یہود کا قبول اسلام :</Content>
                <Br />
                <Content>فرمایا :کہ یہودی اگرچہ آج کل بہت تھوڑے ہیں لیکن وہ اصل میں بہت سے مسلمان ہو گئے تھے جیسا کہ اوپر ایک قصہ بھی بیان کیا ہے کچھ تو آنحضرت صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم کے زمانے میں اور کچھ دیگر سلاطین کے زمانے میں۔ایک شخص کا قصہ ہے کہ اس نے ایک یہودی کو بہت نصیحت کی کہ تم مسلمان ہو جا۔یہودی نے جواب دیا کہ میں جانتا ہوں کہ اسلام کوئی آسان مذہب نہیں ۔صرف منہ سے کہہ دینا کوئی بڑی بات نہیں کہ ہم مسلمان ہیں۔ میں نے اپنے ایک بیٹے کا نام خالد رکھا تھا یعنی ہمیشہ رہنے والا اور دوسرے دن میں اس کو گاڑ بھی آیا تھا ۔پس صرف نام رکھانے سے کچھ نہیں ہوتا۔مگر انسان کا نام رکھا ہوا اگر خطا جاتا  ہے تو خدا کا نہیں۔خدا جس کا نام رکھتا ہے وہی ٹھیک ہوتا ہے۔( صفحہ 158)</Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/heading">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>رہائی</Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/description">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>خواب کے ذریعے امام موسی رضا کی رہائی :</Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/body">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>فرمایا :خدا جب کسی کام کو کرانا ہی چاہتاہے تو گردن سے پکڑ کر بھی کرا دیتا ہے اور اس کے منوانے کے عجیب عجیب رنگ ہیں۔چنانچہ ایک مسلمان بادشاہ کا ذکر ہے کہ اس نے امام موسی ٰرضا کو کسی وجہ سے قید کر دیا ہوا تھا ۔خدا کی قدرت ایک رات بادشاہ نے اپنے وزیر اعظم کو نصف رات  کے وقت بلوایا اور نہایت سخت تاکید کی کہ جس حالت میں ہواسی حالت میں آ جاؤ حتیٰ کے لباس بدلنا بھی تم پر حرام ہے ۔ وزیر حکم پاتے ہی ننگے سر ننگے بدن پر حاضر ہوئے اور اس جلدی اور گھبراہٹ کا باعث دریافت کیا۔بادشاہ نےاپنا ایک خواب بیان کیاکہ میں نے خواب دیکھا ہے کہ ایک حبشی آیا اور اس نے گنڈاسے کی قسم کےایک ہتھیار سےمجھے ڈرایا اور دھمکایا  ہے۔اس کی شکل نہایت پر ہیبت اور خوفناک ہے اس نے مجھے کہا کہ امام موسی ٰکو ابھی چھوڑ دو  ورنہ میں تمہیں ہلاک کر دوں گااور اسے ایک ہزار اشرفی دے کر جہاں اس کا جی چاہےرہنے کی اجازت دو۔سو تم ابھی جاؤ اور امام موسی ٰرضا کو قید سے رہا کردو۔چنانچہ وزیراعظم قید خانہ میں گئے اور قبل اس کے کہ وہ اپنا عندیہ ظاہر کرتے امام موسیٰ رضا بولے کہ پہلے میرا خواب سن لو ۔چنانچہ انہوں نے اپنا خواب یوں بیان کیا کہ اللہ تعالیٰ نے مجھے بشارت دی ہے کہ تم آج ہی قبل اسکے کہ صبح ہوقید سے رہا کئے جاؤگے۔غرض یہ ہیں خدا تعالیٰ کی اقتداری نشانات ۔( صفحہ493)</Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/heading">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>بادل</Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/description">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>خواب میں بادل کا دیکھنا : </Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/body">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>فرمایا : میں نے خواب میں دیکھا تھا کہ بادل چڑھا ہے ۔ میں ڈرا ہوں مگر کسی نے کہا کہ تمہارے لیے مبارک ہے ۔ </Content>
                <Br />
                <Content>قرآن کریم سے بھی ثابت ہے کہ عذاب کو بادل کے رنگ میں دکھایا جاتا ہے ۔ یہ لوگ نشان پر نشان دیکھتے ہیں مگر کچھ پروا نہیں کرتے ۔ یاد رکھو اللہ تعالیٰ اپنے فعل کو عبث نہیں جانے دے گا جو اس کے فعل کو عملی رنگ میں عبث قرار دیتے ہیں وہ ضرور پکڑے جاویں گے ۔ موسیٰؑ کے زمانہ کی طرح ایک نشان سے بڑھ کر دوسرا نشان دکھایا جاتا ہے مگر ان کی فرعونیت فرعون سے بھی بڑھ گئی  اپنی تدبیروں پر بھروسہ رکھتے ہیں ۔ مگر دیکھو کیسی اُلٹی منہ پر پڑتی ہے ۔ رائے ظاہر کی کہ </Content>
                <Br />
                <Content>طاعون اب رو بہ کمی ہے ۔ اس کا کیڑا مر چکا ہے ۔ مگر دیکھو کہ اس سال تمام پچھلے سالوں سے بڑھ کر مری پڑی ہے اور آئندہ دیکھیے کیا ہوتا ہے معلوم ہوتا کہ اس سے بھی بڑھ کر پڑے گی ۔ </Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/heading">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>انفاق فی سبیل اللہ</Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/description">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>پرندوں میں انفاق فی سبیل اﷲ کا سبق</Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/body">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>فرمایا:۔</Content>
                <Br />
                <Content>مرغی اپنے عمل سے دکھاتی ہے کہ کس طرح انفاق فی سبیل اﷲ کرنا چاہیے کیونکہ وہ انسان کی خاطر اپنی ساری جان قربان کرتی ہے اور انسان کے واسطے ذبح کی جاتی ہے۔اسی طرح مرغی نہایت محنت اور مشقت کے ساتھ ہر روز انسان کے واسطے انڈا دیتی ہے۔ </Content>
                <Br />
                <Content>ایسا ہی ایک پرند کی مہمان نوازی پر ایک حکایت ہے کہ ایک درخت کے نیچے ایک مسافر کو رات آگئی۔ جنگل کا دیرانہ اور درسردی کا موسم ۔درخت کے اوپر ایک پرند کاآشیانہ تھا۔ نراور مادہ آپس میں گفتگو کرنے لگے کہ یہ غریب الوطن آج ہمارا مہمان ہے اور سردی زدہ ہے۔ اس کے واسطے ہم کیا کریں؟ سوچ کر ان میں یہ صلاح قرار پائی کہ ہم اپنا آشیانہ توڑ کر نیچے پھینک دیں اوروہ اس کو جلا کر آگ تاپے؛ چنانچہ انہوں نے کہا کہ یہ بھوکا ہے۔ اس کے واسطے کیا دعوت تیار کی جائے۔اور تو کوئی چیز موجود نہ تھی۔ ان دونی نے اپنے آپ کو نیچے اس آگ میں گرادیا، تا کہ ان کے گوشت کا کباب ان کے مہمان کے واسطے رات کا کھانا ہو جائے۔ اس طرح انہوں نے مہمان نوازی کی ایک نظیر قائم کی۔ سو ہماری جماعت کے مومنین اگر ہماری آواز کو نہیں سنتے تو اس مرغی کی آواز کو سنیں۔ مگر سب برابر نہیں۔ کتنے مخلص ایسے ہیں کہ اپنی طاقت سے زیادہ خدمت میں لگے ہوئے ہیں۔ خدا تعالیٰ ان کو جزائے خیر د ے۔(صفحہ582,583).</Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/heading">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>سبحان اﷲ کے معنی</Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/description">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>ایک شخص نے اپنا خواب سنایا کہ میں سبحان اﷲ پڑھتا ہوں۔ فرمایا :</Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/body">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>سبحان اﷲ کے یہ معنے ہیں کہ اﷲ تعالیٰ خلاف وعدہ اور کذب اور دیگر تمام منقصتوں سے پاک ہے وہ اپنے وعدوں کو سچا کرتا اور پیشگوئیوں کو پورا کرتا ہے۔میں نے مناسب سمجھا ہے کہ اس واسطے ایک اور اشتہار لکھا جاوے۔ بار بار کے سمجھانے سے ممکن ہے کہ کوئی آدمی سمجھ جاوے۔(صفحہ280)</Content>
                <Br />
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/heading">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>فتح /دشمن</Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/body">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>تَبَّتۡ یَدَاۤ اَبِیۡ لَہَبٍ وَّتَبَّ خواب میں پڑھنے پر فر مایاکہ کسی دشمن پر فتح ہوگی (صفحہ623)</Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/heading">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>تعبیر </Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/description">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>خوابوں کی تعبیر ہر ایک کے حال کے مطابق ہوتی ہے</Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
        <ParagraphStyleRange AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/body">
            <CharacterStyleRange AppliedCharacterStyle="CharacterStyle/$ID/[No character style]">
                <Content>فرمایا :-</Content>
                <Br />
                <Content>خوابوں کی تعبیر ہر ایک کے حال کے موافق مختلف ہوا کرتی ہے ایک دفعہ ابن سیرین کے پاس ایک شخص آیا اور بیان کیا کہ میں نے خواب میں دیکھا کہ میں ایک کوڑے کے ڈھیر پر ننگا کھڑا ہوں۔ابن سیرین نے کہا کہ اگر کوئی اور شخص کافر یا فاسق اس خواب کو بیان کرتا تو میں اس کی تعبیر اور بیان کرتا۔مگر تو اس تعبیر کے لائق نہیں ہے اس لئے سن کہ کوڑے اور کھاد سے مراد تو دنیا ہے جس میں تو موجود زندہ ہے اور ننگے ہونے سے مراد یہ ہے کہ تیرے صفات حسنہ سب لوگوں پر کھلے ہیں کیونکہ ننگا ہونے سے انسان کا سب ظاہر ہوجاتا ہے اسی طرح لگو تیری خوبیاں دیکھ رہے ہیں تو مطلب اس سے یہ ہے کہ صالح آدمی کے خواب کی تعبیر اور ہوتی ہے اور شقی کی اور۔( صفحہ623) </Content>
                <Br />
            </CharacterStyleRange>
        </ParagraphStyleRange>
    </Story>
</idPkg:Story>
```

I have written following Regex for use in Notepad++

`(?:\G(?!^)|<Content)>\K(.*?)(?=<)`

regex101 shows Matches but it is not extracting the matched text.

Here is the link to the query in Regex101
[Regex101 Query](https://regex101.com/r/CE0iBt/1)

I also want to improve this query.

Comment: What is it supposed to look like after the replacement? Does `<Content>(\K.+?)(?=<\/Content>)` not work for the find string?

Comment: ```(?:\G(?!^)|<Content)>\K(.*?)(?=<\/Content>)``` This code also gives the same result.

After the replacement there should be only Arabic Characters left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\A|\G).*?<content>(.+?)</content>(?:(?!<content>).)*`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **TICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:\A|\G)               # non capture group, begining of file or restart from last match position
.*?                     # 0 or more any character
<content>               # literally
(.+?)                   # group 1, 1 or more any character
</content>              # literally
(?:(?!<content>).)*     # 0 or more any character that don't match "<content>"
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Toto. I tried the code and it worked. however, it is putting all the matches in a single line so I modified the replace with `\r\n$1` and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

#### I am trying to extract Arabic text between the two tags

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `(<Content>)(.+?)(<\/Content>)`
- Set "Replace with" to `\2`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

[image]

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation?](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Thanks David. I tried the code. It works, but it does not remove the other unwanted tags.